# Is there a way to dispute a question that has been down voted and closed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is there a way to dispute a question that has been down voted and closed? For example I don't know why I got down voted for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091883/ranking-functions-from-smallest-big-oh-to-largest

Some say my question was too specific, I'd say the answers given were too specific.

Comment: Questions: 1) `Some say my question was too specific, I'd say the answers given were too specific.` Assuming that's true, why is this your counter-argument? Answers are supposed to be specific. 2) In which category of [on topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) do you think yours is? 3) The close notification read `This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors;...` Do you dispute that? Care to elaborate?

Comment: The sad irony. A question about a question being downvoted, being downvoted :/

Comment: @Yannis Rizos Homework questions are allowed. This question comes from a popular textbook. I certainly made an effort to solve it myself (which is why I'm supprised it got down voted). "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitor" if a question is suppose to be specific then how can it help others without the same question? If one of the replies actually told me how to tell for myself then that answer would be general and possibly helpful to others. But I ask this question in a general sense, not nescecarilly exclusivly about the ranking functions question.

Comment: Well, homework questions are allowed, but they still need to be on one of the general topics discussed in the [FAQ], and follow all the other guidelines in there. Also the close notification said quite a few other things, not just This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitor, don't get stuck on that, although in this case, it certainly was [unlikely to ever help any future visitor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121254/162704). And please, if you are really on a quest for knowledge, spell it correctly.

Comment: `If one of the replies actually told me how to tell for myself then that answer would be general and possibly helpful to others.` But you didn't ask that, did you?

Answer (score 6):

The closure reason was:

> closed as too localized

You've got a discrete list of functions that you want to order and you've asked if the order you've come up with is correct, so unless someone else comes along in the future and needs to know the order of that exact same list, it's too localised to be of any use to anyone else.

Now, if you'd said something like:

> I've ordered this list of functions with respect to big-oh notation, by using this algorithm I've written in [C#/perl/etc]:
>
> .. // Code of algorithm here
>
> I'm not confident that my algorithm has ordered items 16 and 17 the right way round, perhaps because I think line 6 of my algorithm isn't quite right, but I'm not sure why.

THEN, it would:

- contain code
- be useful to more than one person

Answer (score 4):

I'd say your question is off-topic. There is no programming angle to it, it's just math.

I don't know *why* you got downvoted, you'd have to peek into each downvoter's mind to answer that, and there is no such mind-reading feature on Stack Exchange yet. But your question does not belong on Stack Overflow in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, mind-reading is a 350k+ privilege.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.